# AI/ML Assisted labeling in Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

Is there a feature in Vertex AI which will allow AI/ML to assist in labeling data? This usually works by providing a small set of labeled data, followed by a model creation which assists in labeling more data. As more and more data is labeled the model keeps getting better.

Comment: I believe there is no documentation recorded for this method at the moment, as users usually need to manually label their images/videos to feed for training(or datasets that has already assigned labels). If you require to label a large number of media you can request human labelers to label for you. For reference please visit this link: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/data-labeling-job

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it:

1. From the left panel in VertexAi select "Labeling Tasks"
2. Add a new Labeling Task ("create" button)
3. In the menu for creating the task there is a checkbox with "Active Learning"

From VertexAi: **Use active learning**
*Active learning accelerates the labeling process by applying partial labeling to data with a human labeler, followed by applying machine learning techniques to automatically label what remains.*

Reference code: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/samples/aiplatform-create-data-labeling-job-active-learning-sample

Answer (score 0):

Yes. After you feed your images and it is loaded into the labeling UI, there is a button near the top right of the interface for auto labeling. Auto labeling does cost money though so I would be wary in doing it.

A much much quicker way of labeling is to import your images in sections. What I mean is, suppose you want an AI that can tell the difference between an Apple and a Pear. What I would do (and did for a similar project) is import all of the Apple images first, create a label for Apples, then filter your images to 50-100 a page and just select all and move those images to the Apple label. Its a much faster way and would also save you some money and time because according to my knowledge, sending in an automatic labeling task can be very costly depending on how big your data size is. I am pretty sure that automatic labeling is also a human hired job and can't be done with AI. If it were to be done with AI though for lets say 1,000,000 images, you would have to go through the images and correct any mistakes that the AI may make.

Hopefully this helps !!

Answer (score -1):

This might accomplish what you want, in vertex or any solution. By the nature of what needs to happen I don't think there can be a shortcut but of course automation is possible.

1. Train a classification model on a set with known labels
2. Use this model to estimate labels for new data
3. Periodically, once you get more labeled data (ideally truly labeled, but you could try including things for which the label was estimated), then retrain the model